# How to make strings from floating-point numbers with '.' (dot) as a decimal separator and not more than 3 digits after floating point?

Tags: java, string, format, number-formatting

I have this code:

```
public String formatDouble(double d) {
   return String.format("???", d); //Should I use NumberFormat here?
}
```

For the sample input:

```
1.00
1,00
1,23
1.234567
```

I would like to get this output:

```
1
1
1.23
1.234
```

How can I configure the pattern (or maybe NumberFormat instance) for producing the correct output?

Answer (score 2):

This would do roughly what you need:

```
Decimalformat df = new DecimalFormat("0.###");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
df.format(1.2345);
```

However, the decimal separator (the dot) will be dependent on current locale. To override it, you may want to provide your own format symbols (see `DecimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols()`).

Answer (score 1):

Simple way: `String.format("%.2f", 1234.23)`

If you need thousand separator, add a comma before the dot: `String.format("%,.2f", 1234.23)` -> the result: `1,234.23`.

Answer (score 0):

[DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) should do what you need.