# working decimal point numbers

Tags: java, floating-point-precision

I wrote a program in java about floating point but the output obtained is not an accurate one; whereas the same program written in C did produce an accurate result.

Code Snippet:

```
public class One {

public static void main(String...args){

    double i, num=0.0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    num=num+0.1;
    System.out.println(num);

    }
}
```

**output**: 0.9999999999999999

The program in C goes like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{

double i,num=0.0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
num=num+0.1;

printf("%f",num);

}
```

**output**:1.00000

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why you are not tagged with c?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make strings from floating-point numbers with '.' (dot) as a decimal separator and not more than 3 digits after floating point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712504/how-to-make-strings-from-floating-point-numbers-with-dot-as-a-decimal-sepa)

Comment: Have you tried using the equivalent `printf` in Java? You are comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 5):

### C is hiding the problem not removing it

The idea that the C program is more accurate is a misunderstanding of what is happening. Both have imprecise answers but then by default C has rounded to 6 significant figures. **Hiding** the tiny error. Were you to actually use the value in a calculation (for example `num==1`) you'd find that both are inaccurate.

### Usually it doesn't matter for well written programs

In general intelligently written programs can cope with this tiny error without difficulty. For example your program can be rewritten to recreate a double each time

```
double i, num=0.0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   num=0.1*i;
   System.out.println(num);

}
```

Meaning that the error does not grow. Additionally you should never use == with doubles as the tiny inaccuracy can be visible there.

In the very very occasional occurrences where this tiny error is a problem (currency programs being the most common); bigDecimal can be used.

### This isn't a problem with floating point numbers but with the conversion from base 10 to base 2.

There are fractions in base 10 that cannot be expressed exactly; for example 1/3. Similarly there are fractions that cannot be expressed exactly within binary for example 1/10. [It is from this perspective that you should look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19907216/2187042)

The problem in this case was that when you wrote "0.1", a base 10 number the computer had to convert that to a binary number,     `0.1=(binary)0.00011001100110011001100110011001.......` forever but because it couldn't exactly represent that in binary with the space it had it ended up as `(binary)0.000110011001100`<sup>1</sup>. A binary friendly number (such as 1/2) would be completely accurate until the double ran out of precision digits (at which point even binary friendly numbers couldn't be exactly represented)

<sup>1</sup> number of decimal places not accurate

Answer (score 2):

Try using `BigDecimal`. Floating point number representation is an old moot point of Java (and not only).

```
double i;
BigDecimal num = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    num = num.add(new BigDecimal("0.1"));
System.out.println(num);
```

Comment: It's a wierd situation, java was honest about it whereas c tries to hide it and as such java is seen as less accurate, *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with Java, but about how computers represent floating point numbers in binary. Some numbers are impossible to represent exactly, so you get a little bit of rounding error as you add `0.1`. I suggest you read [this great article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for a detailed explanation. Also, there are [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) specifically designed to minimise error when adding a sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in `floating` number representation. use `BigDecimal`

You can understand the issue here. if you run following code,

```
    double i, num=0.0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        System.out.println(num);
        num=num+0.1;
    }
    System.out.println(num);
```

Out put

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004 // wrong value, it should be 0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999 // this one should be 0.7+0.1=0.8
0.8999999999999999 // this should be 0.8+0.1=0.9
0.9999999999999999 // final result should be 0.9+0.1=1
```

Let's try with `BigDeciaml`

```
 double i;
 BigDecimal num=BigDecimal.ZERO;
 for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
     System.out.println(num);
     num=num.add(new BigDecimal("0.1"));
   }
 System.out.println(num);
```

Out put

```
0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `strictfp` keyword, like:

```
strictfp class Example
{
    //your code here
}
```

`strictfp` is a keyword introduced in Java SE 2(or somewhere near that) as the floating point model was relaxed a little.

Comment: Could you explain what `strictfp` means/does

Comment: By my reading strictfp ensures equivalent floating point behaviour on all systems rather than using a base-10 number system rather than a base-2

Comment: @RichardTingle Base-10 has nothing to do with floating-point. `strictfp` just ensures IEEE754 compliance via whatever means are necessary, e.g. using software instead of FP instructions.

Comment: @EPJ that's my point, that strictfp doesn't impact this problem; representing base-10 numbers in a base-2 system (floating point would cause issues eventually but its the base-10 --> base-2 where most of the problem lies)